# Can I link a Stack Exchange website like AskUbuntu or Facebook to my website

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

I have a website where users can do practice their subjects.

Can I have a Stack Exchange website like [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) or [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) for my website for the doubts clarification of users?

What is the process to configure such website so that when a user got a doubt in his/her subject a link will be given to post the question in the Stack Exchange website and the doubt will be clarified?

Is there any restriction for commercial websites?

I have gone through different answers related to Stack Overflow clone but the process of configuring is not clear.